# jQuery $.post needs JSON response parsed manually all of a sudden

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, post

I'm calling to the server using jQuery's `$.post` method and assigning the JSON response to a variable called `result`. The response is an array in PHP's `json_encode()` function.

Up until now I've always just used the properties of `result` directly, as the JSON gets parsed into an object automatically. But now, after some debugging, I've found that my code only works when I use `JSON.parse(result)` first.

What could've caused this sudden change?

**Solution:** Adding `header("Content-Type: application/json")` serverside when echoing a JSON encoded response.

Comment: It's depends on server's header `Content-Type: application/json`, maybe server stoped to send this header

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either:

1. Your server stopped setting the correct `Content-Type` response header (`application/json`). PHP will claim anything it sends to the browser is `text/html` unless you use the `header()` function to override that.
2. You didn't say `type: 'json'` to make jQuery (a) set an `Accept` header and (more relevantly) (b) ignore the response's `Content-Type` header and try to parse it as JSON regardless.

Comment: Thank you! I needed to set the Content-Type header before any JSON responses as you say. It's strange that I never needed to do that before actually. Only change I've made recently is resinstalling xampp so it's on PHP 8, I can only guess that might've been the cause of it.

Also worth noting that this slowed down my site hugely without the content type header, even when it handled the response successfully.